# How to install GStreamer plugin having "MPEG-2 Transport Stream demuxer" element on windows

Tags: windows, plugins, gstreamer

I have installed GStreamer on windows using .msi files from the following link -
[gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.2.0.msi](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.0/gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.2.0.msi)
and
[gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.2.0.msi](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.2.0/gstreamer-1.0-devel-x86-1.2.0.msi)

I can run the following command and play .webm video files without any problem.`gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="file:///D:/gstreamer_sample_media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"`

But when I try to play a test .mts file using the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="file:///D:/MyTestMedia/Test1.mts"
```

The following error comes out:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Missing element: MPEG-2 Transport Stream demuxer
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: No dec
oder available for type 'video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(i
nt)192'.
Additional debug info:
gsturidecodebin.c(930): unknown_type_cb (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin
:uridecodebin0
ERROR: from element /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecode
Bin:decodebin0: Your GStreamer installation is missing a plug-in.
Additional debug info:
gstdecodebin2.c(3896): gst_decode_bin_expose (): /GstPlayBin:playbin0/GstURIDeco
deBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0:
no suitable plugins found
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

I know that to be able to play .mts file I have to install gst-plugins-bad-1.2.0 plugins and have missing "MPEG-2 Transport Stream demuxer" element.

The problem is I don't know how to do it in windows 7 or windows 8 OS (32 or 64 bit versions).

I downloaded the following files
[gst-plugins-base-1.2.0](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/snapshot/gst-plugins-base-1.2.0.zip),
[gst-plugins-good-1.2.0](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/snapshot/gst-plugins-good-1.2.0.zip),
[gst-plugins-bad-1.2.0](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/snapshot/gst-plugins-bad-1.2.0.zip),
[gst-plugins-ugly-1.2.0](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-ugly/snapshot/gst-plugins-ugly-1.2.0.zip).
But the precompiled .dll files for windows were not inside them. Also I tried to compile them for windows, but just was able to do so for some projects in gst-plugins-base and it seems compiling gst-plugins-bad requires a lot of effort and I was unable to do so by now.

Is there any link to download pre-build .dlls of gst-plugins-bad for windows? And if we download them where they has to be copied so that gst-launch-1.0.exe can recognize them? Are they just need to be copied in `E:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin` where gstreamer is installed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably did a **'typical'** install of the gstreamer SDK.

Reinstall and make sure you select the **'complete'** features before installing. This should include the gst-plugins-bad packages.

Comment: Thank you. This was the case. I reinstalled using "complete" features and now mpegtsdemux is available.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using gstreamer-sdk? It can be found on [GStreamer.com](http://gstreamer.com). The official releases are 0.10 only, but you can easily find builds for 1.x on the mailing lists: [here for 1.2](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/RELEASE-GStreamer-1-2-0-binaries-for-Android-Mac-OS-X-and-Windows-td4662195.html)

Comment: Yes thiagoss, I have tried them too. Those binaries does not include gstreamer plugins. mpeg2 ts demuxer is in gst-plugins-bad and I don't know were I could find Windows binaries for gstreamer plugins and how to install them.

Comment: @yashil You probably did a 'typical' install of gstreamer SDK. Reinstall and make sure you select the 'complete' features before installing. This should include the gst-plugins-bad packages.